# how to download "rtsp" flow

Tags: downloads, rm, media

I could download a conference from this link (rtsp://real2.infn.it/webcast/2012-esploratori-invisibile/esploratori-dell-invisibile.rm).
How can I do it?

Thank you previuosly..

Answer (score 4):

The program `rtmpdump` should be able to handle this as well:

install:

```
sudo apt-get install rtmpdump
```

save file:

```
rtmpdump -r rtsp://real2.infn.it/webcast/2012-esploratori-invisibile/esploratori-dell-invisibile.rm -o myfile.rm
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) (available in the [software center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc/)), use the Convert/Save option under the Media menu. The first dialog will request an input, select the Network tab and paste the URL that you'd like in it. The next step is to pick where you want to save it, and finally what format you want it in. Hit the Start button and let it go.

Comment: Thanks but not work .. I tried four times, but the download stops at 02:34

Comment: Odd. RTSP streams can be hard to rip, If you want to give it another go, you could try the "Display Output" option on the Convert/Save dialog (directly below the file selection box for where you want to save the output). That might give you some hint as to what's going on. Additionally, you could [try this method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CaptureRTSP) that I found by Googling

Comment: Thank you, it works..  I used this command: `mplayer -dumpstream rtsp://real2.infn.it/webcast/2012-esploratori-invisibile/esploratori-dell-invisibile.rm -dumpfile esploratori-dell-invisibile.rm`